# How to Change Data from the right side to the left by clicking using EF

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to know how can I change my data from the right side to the left by clicking correctly using Entity Framework. The data is in spanish, sorry for that but I can´t change it.

Here is my View where I can only change the "Titulo" that means in enlgish Title and the Content but I have problem with my DateTime and my Images that become a related table and with int data. The Id change because it appears in the right side (I dont want to show the Image and Id data in the right side).

[image]

To show the principal Image I use this `@foreach` where I get the data from the second table called "Noticias1" that means in english News1 where are the Image data for every News and `if (img != null && img.Nombre.Equals(@principalId+"_0"))` to show me only the Principal Img that is equal to the selected Id (I will show the others Img behind the content.)

Here the code

```
@foreach (var n in Model) 
{
  var img = n.Noticias2.FirstOrDefault(); 
  if (img != null && img.Nombre.Equals(@principalId+"_0")) 
  {
    var imgRuta = @img.Ruta+@img.Nombre+@img.Extension; 
    <img id="currentprincipalImagen" src="@imgRuta" class="img-responsive" alt="Imagen de Marte" />
    <figcaption>
      <p id="currentPrincipalImagenTitulo">@img.Descripcion</p>
    </figcaption>
   }
}
```

Here is my full view code

```
@{
    var format = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"; 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
    int principalId = Model[0].IdNoticia; 
    string principalTitulo = Model[0].Titulo; 
    string principalContenido = Model[0].Contenido;
    DateTime principalFechaDesde = Convert.ToDateTime(Model[0].FeDesde);
    DateTime principalFechaHasta = Convert.ToDateTime(Model[0].FeHasta);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDisplay(e) {

        var principalTitulo = $(e).text(); 
        var principalContenido = $(e).siblings(".Contenido:first").html(); 
        var principalId = $(e).siblings(".IdNoticia:first").html();
        var principalFechaDesde = $(e).siblings(".FeDesde").html();


        $("#currentprincipalTitulo").html(principalTitulo);
        $("#currentprincipalContenido").html(principalContenido);
        $("#currentprincipalId").html(principalId);
        $("#currentprincipalFechaDesde").html(principalFechaDesde);
    }
</script>

<!-- Principal -->
<div class="col-md-12 main">

    <div class="header sec-title-hd">
        <div class="bg-calendar"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h5 class="pull-left">NOTICIAS</h5>
            <div>
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="btn sky-blue n-radius-b"> <img src="slider/img/arrow-left.png"> VOLVER</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-inter">
        <div class="container-fluid sec-title-hd-sub">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div>
                        <figure class="img_N">
                            @foreach (var n in Model) 
                            {
                                var img = n.Noticias2.FirstOrDefault(); 
                                if (img != null && img.Nombre.Equals(@principalId+"_0")) 
                                {
                                    var imgRuta = @img.Ruta+@img.Nombre+@img.Extension; 
                                    <img id="currentprincipalImagen" src="@imgRuta" class="img-responsive" alt="Imagen de Marte" />
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <p id="currentPrincipalImagenTitulo">@img.Descripcion</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                }
                            }
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="textnota">
                        <br>
                        <h6 id="currentprincipalId">@principalId</h6>
                        <h5 id="currentprincipalTitulo" class="titulo_N uppercase">@principalTitulo</h5>
                        <p id="currentprincipalFechaDesde" class="time">FeDesde: @principalFechaDesde.ToString(format)</p> 
                        <div class="noti_P">
                            <p id="currentprincipalContenido">@principalContenido</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <!-- Right Side -->
                    @foreach (var n in Model)
                    {

                        <blockquote class="blockquote-nopadding bg-calendar-border-left">
                            <h6 class="IdNoticia">@n.IdNoticia</h6>
                            <p class="time_f feDesde">@n.FeDesde.ToString(format)</p>
                            <a href="#" onclick="changeDisplay(this)" class="titulo_N">@n.Titulo</a>
                            <p class="text-justify limit Contenido">@n.Contenido</p>
                        </blockquote>
                    }
                    Págnia @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks. I know that in my Jquery Script code I dont have something to change the Image but I remove this because I cant do the relation to change the Id into the `@foreach` in the left side to changue my principal Image. my english is not good I hope you could understand me.

Here is the relation where If I click the first with Id = 1 I want to get the images from that Id and the same with Id = 2, 3, 4...

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: That im not doing that right, if you see the image I clicked the New with id 2 and it has data from Id 1.

Comment: @Mehmet the Jquery Code only copy the right side data and change it in the left side data but there are information that Is not in the right side and i dont want to show it there, so I cant do the same code for that.

Comment: did you find answer?

Comment: @Mehmet yes 50% by my self, now I am looking for the logic to change the Images. after that I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution, the problem was in my Jquery code. Maybe it is not the best way to do it in Entity Framework but this is how I solve this. (If you have a better way please share it).

Here my full new code.

```
@{
    var format = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"; 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
    int principalId = Model[0].IdNoticia; 
    string principalTitulo = Model[0].Titulo; 
    string principalContenido = Model[0].Contenido;
    DateTime principalFechaDesde = Convert.ToDateTime(Model[0].FeDesde);
    DateTime principalFechaHasta = Convert.ToDateTime(Model[0].FeHasta);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDisplay(e) {

        var principalTitulo = $(e).text(); 
        var principalContenido = $(e).siblings(".Contenido:first").val(); 
        var principalId = $(e).siblings(".IdNoticia:first").val(); 
        var principalFechaDesde = $(e).siblings(".FeDesde:first").val();
        var principalFechaHasta = $(e).siblings(".FeHasta:first").val();
        var principalDescripcion = $(e).siblings(".Descripcion:first").val();
        var principalImagen = $(e).siblings(".imgRuta").val();


        $("#currentprincipalTitulo").html(principalTitulo);
        $("#currentprincipalContenido").html(principalContenido);
        $("#currentprincipalId").html(principalId);
        $("#currentprincipalFechaDesde").html(principalFechaDesde);
        $("currentprincipalFechaHasta").html(principalFechaHasta);
        $("#currentprincipalDescripcion").html(principalDescripcion);
        $("#currentprincipalImagen").attr("src", principalImagen);
    }
</script>

<!-- Principal -->
<div class="col-md-12 main">

    <div class="header sec-title-hd">
        <div class="bg-calendar"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h5 class="pull-left">NOTICIAS</h5>
            <div>
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="btn sky-blue n-radius-b"> <img src="slider/img/arrow-left.png"> VOLVER</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-inter">
        <div class="container-fluid sec-title-hd-sub">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div>
                        <figure class="img_N">
                            @foreach (var n in Model) 
                            {
                                var img = n.Noticias2.FirstOrDefault(); 
                                if (img != null && img.Nombre.Equals(@principalId+"_0")) 
                                {
                                    <img id="currentprincipalImagen" src="@img.Ruta@img.Nombre@img.Extension" class="img-responsive" alt="@img.Nombre" />
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <p id="currentprincipalDescripcion">@img.Descripcion</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                }
                            }
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="textnota">
                        <br>
                        <h6 id="currentprincipalId">@principalId</h6>
                        <h5 id="currentprincipalTitulo" class="titulo_N uppercase">@principalTitulo</h5>
                        <p id="currentprincipalFechaDesde" class="time">Desde: @principalFechaDesde.ToString(format)</p> 
                        <p id="currentprincipalFechaHasta" class="time">Hasta: @principalFechaHasta.ToString(format)</p> 
                        <div class="noti_P">
                            <p id="currentprincipalContenido">@principalContenido</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <!-- Right Side -->
                    @foreach (var n in Model)
                    {
                        <!-- Data mostrada -->
                        <blockquote class="blockquote-nopadding bg-calendar-border-left">
                            <p class="time_f">@n.FeDesde.ToString(format)</p>
                            <a href="#" onclick="changeDisplay(this)" class="titulo_N">@n.Titulo</a>
                            <p class="text-justify limit">@n.Contenido</p>

                            <!--Data Enviada al lado Izquierdo-->
                            <input class="IdNoticia" type="hidden" value="@n.IdNoticia" />
                            <input class="Contenido" type="hidden" value="@n.Contenido" />
                            <input class="FeDesde" type="hidden" value="Desde: @n.FeDesde.ToString(format)" />
                            <input class="FeHasta" type="hidden" value="Hasta: @n.FeHasta.ToString(format)" />
                            @foreach (var img in n.Noticias2)
                            {
                                var imgRuta = @img.Ruta + @img.Nombre + @img.Extension;
                                <input class="Descripcion" type="hidden" value="@img.Descripcion" />

                                <input class="imgRuta" type="hidden" value="@imgRuta" />
                            }

                        </blockquote>

                    }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the new view,

> notice that all the data in the left side are from the id 2.

[image]